# Should I use standard definitions or computations to figure out length of allowable ranges of data types in C

Tags: c, types

Looking through the `limits.h` file, I noticed that it contained information about the number of bits that a `char` contains on my system and also the maximum allowable values of certain data types.

```
/* Number of bits in a `char'.  */
#undef CHAR_BIT
#define CHAR_BIT __CHAR_BIT__

/* Maximum value an `unsigned char' can hold.  (Minimum is 0).  */
#undef UCHAR_MAX
#define UCHAR_MAX 255
```

My question is, should I use these definitions in my programs or should I somehow compute the allowable values. I tried to create an example, but am not entirely certain if what I've done makes sense.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    int numberOfBitsInChar = CHAR_BIT;
    printf("Maximum size of unsigned char: %.0f\n", pow(2.0, (double)numberOfBitsInChar) - 1);
    printf("Maximum size of unsigned char: %i\n", UCHAR_MAX);
    return 0;
}
```

The first `printf()` uses a computation to obtain the maximum size of an unsigned char and the second `printf()` uses the appropriate definition. I have also seen the following code used as well.

```
printf("Maximum Unsigned Char %d\n",(unsigned char)~0);
```

I am wondering what the recommended practice of finding data type limits is, or if either approach (using the appropriate definition or by computation) is acceptable.

Comment: Use the definitions. This is why they are provided.

Comment: Absolutely use the definitions.  All else apart, they're more likely to be usable in the preprocessor than computations you do in your code.  And it's hard to choose different types after the program is compiled.  The problem comes when you need information that is available on some platforms but not on others — then it gets messier.

Comment: Understood, thank you, wasn't sure which way to go.

Comment: Only the values from `limit.h` should be used in general. C doesn't give any guarantees about the representation of signed and float types, so trying to calculate something for these could gibe wrong results.

Comment: Use %u (or %x, or %o with or without h or hh) to print unsigned values: `printf("%u", (unsigned char)~0);`. You invoke UB on implementations where `sizeof (char) == sizeof (int)` otherwise.

Comment: alos you have a limit as to what is discoverable. In you example you worked out the max value of an unsigned char, but you used as input CHAR_BIT. How would you calculate CHAR_BIT? You reach the point where you cannot find things out without straying into UB